# What are the numbers dispalyed next to author from for-each-ref

Tags: git

So I have been trying to use the --format option in the for-each-ref command, and when I run this command:

```
git for-each-ref --format='%(author)'
```

I get this output:

```
Pat McGroin <McGrion.Pat@example.com> 1529175479 -0600
```

What are those numbers at the end? What do they represent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The number immediately after the author email appears to be a UNIX timestamp:

```
1529175479 -0600
 ^^ UNIX timestamp
```

The value `1529175479` value corresponds to the date `02/21/2018 @ 2:02am (UTC)`.  You may convince yourself of this by converting the number online: https://www.unixtimestamp.com/index.php

Comment: I think I understand. When I looked it up online I got `06/16/2018 @ 6:57pm (UTC)` as the time, how did you look yours up? Also this means that the -0600 is the offset for the timezone, correct?

Comment: I'm not entirely certain of the syntax, but yes `-0600` appears to be a timezone offset.